# How to add custom data to marker (Google Maps API SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to figure out a way to add custom properties/data for my marker.

**What I have used**

- Marker.Title (Store Title)
- Marker.Snippet (Store object Id)
- Marker.Icon (Store icon)
- Marker.userData(to store
  image)

**Additional Information I'd like to store to display on InfoWindow**

- Description(String)
- A number(Int)

It would be nice if there are more efficient ways of storing and retrieving custom data/properties to display on the infowindow. Any suggestions would be valuable at the moment.

**Here is a snippet of what I have at the moment:** 
Setting Marker Data:

```
 marker.title = object["objectTitle"] as! String
 marker.snippet = objecti.objectId
 marker.icon = UIImage(named:"markerImage")
 marker.userData = UIImage(data:imageData!)
```

Info Window:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
    var infoWindow :CustomInfoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("eventInfo", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomInfoWindow

    infoWindow.eventTitle.text = marker.title

    infoWindow.Image.image = marker.userData as? UIImage
    marker.userData = UIImage(data:imageData!)
     marker.snippet = object.objectId
    return infoWindow
}
```

Comment: You can also store the  data in `NSUserDefault` or just `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created a struct that has all the data i need and put it in marker.userdata since it supports Any type.

```
let data = structName(lat: place.lat, long: place.long) // initialize struct
marker.userData = data
```

Aceess it like this:

```
let markerLat = (marker.userData as! structName).lat
let markerLong = (marker.userData as! structName).long
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No probs @htjohn

Answer (score 12):

I came across your question while just starting to learn Swift, but do you think something like this would work:

```
var myData = Dictionary<String, Any>()
myData["image"] = UIImage(data:imageData!)
myData["description"] = "The description"
myData["number"] = 1
marker.userData = myData
```

It's a technique to store multiple data types that I just learned about recently.

Comment: How would I retrieve the Dictionary Properties within userData? Because userData does not have a subscript.

Comment: Really great solution. Could you please tell me how did you retrieve the data stored in marker.userData?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. It's been too long since I was experimenting with it.

Comment: struct data type seems to be the way to go here vs dictionary (see Gamz Rs answer).